# backbone on rails collection fetch does not work except in javascript console

Tags: ruby-on-rails, json, backbone.js, coffeescript

## Update:

Forget about the first attempt, in my "another attempt", it works with firefox but fails in google chrome. The reason seems to be the alert pop up in firefox allows enough time for the collection to fetch the data, it returns 0 again (instead of 2) after I remove the alert. It seems the on('reset',.. ) is bypassed

---

I am new to backbone and was testing things out so I have

collection file:

```
class Blog.Collections.Posts extends Backbone.Collection

  model: Blog.Models.Post

  url: '/bb/posts/list_posts'
```

models file:

```
class Blog.Models.Post extends Backbone.Model
```

router file:

```
class Blog.Routers.Posts extends Backbone.Router
  routes: 'posts/list' : 'list'

  list: ->
    @collection = new Blog.Collections.Posts()
    @collection.fetch success: ->
       alert @collection
       view = new Blog.Views.PostsIndex()
       $('#center').html(view.render(posts: @collection).el)
```

view file:

```
 class Blog.Views.PostsIndex extends Backbone.View

   template: JST['posts/index']


   render: (posts) -> 
      $(@el).html(@template(posts))
      this
```

template file just displays the length of the posts. So when the collection fetches the json from the /bb/posts/list_posts url, I should wait for it to finish with success. But somehow the alert **returns undefined** and template renders length 0

Another attempt:

router file:

```
class Blog.Routers.Posts extends Backbone.Router
  routes: 'posts/list' : 'list'

  list: ->
    @collection = new Blog.Collections.Posts()
    @collection.fetch()
    view = new Blog.Views.PostsIndex(collection: @collection)
    $('#center').html(view.render().el)
```

view file:

```
 class Blog.Views.PostsIndex extends Backbone.View

   template: JST['posts/index']

   initialize: ->
     @collection.on('reset',@render,this)
     alert @collection.length

   render: -> 
     $(@el).html(@template(posts: @collection))
     this
```

this time, I get the alert @collection to return Object[Object] but it has length 0.

The fetch works FINE in javascript console and length is 2. Why doesn't it work?

Comment: just fixed a bit of indentation, doesn't fix the problem. but it looks better now

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Found the solution here

[Backbone.js - fetch method does not fire reset event](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15959306/backbone-js-fetch-method-does-not-fire-reset-event)

As it turns out, the problem being the 'reset' event was never fired. As is pointed out in the link, instead of fetch(), fetch({reset:true}) solves the problem. : )

Comment: The behavior of `fetch` changed in Backbone 1.0.0, it used to `reset` the collection but now it doesn't (unless you ask it to with the `reset: true` option) so a lot of older tutorials and code will be out of date.

Comment: Accept your own answer please to hide it from list of unanswered questions.

Comment: says I can't accept it until 2 days later which is 9 hours away.